# Sci-fi book series with modern Arthurian legends with Excalibur as a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, books, arthurian

I think this was actually a series of books following the human survivors of an alien invasion of Earth. Set a little into the future though I don't think it's by much. Strangely the aliens have ships which are nuclear-based and not much more advanced technology-wise than second world war.

I think Morgana is featured in there as the person who advanced the aliens' intelligence to the point they became space bound and then encouraged them to invade.

Merlin is also featured as a dotty but powerful old man with Excalibur being an excessively advanced high tech spaceship which "Arthur" is the only one who can mentally connect to in order to fly it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find much about it online, but the *Dyason* series by Warren James Palmer has similar elements.

Summary of the first book, *Empire of the minds* (1995), from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XW7J6XG):

> By the year 2045 the United Nations World Defence Force can finally guarantee the security of every nation on the planet through the use of orbital laser battle stations.
>   That is until the day the Dyason arrived. The Dyason are humanoid, but not from our star system. In a blitzkrieg attack they wipe out the World Defence Force and within days, force worldwide capitulation. except for a few renegades, mankind is enslaved.
>
> Out of the prison ghettos of London a new hero emerges, a youth with exceptional mental powers. Minds of the Empire follows Moss as he struggles to escape the rubble of London and flee from both the Dyason and the Resistance.

Checks:

- not too far future (2045), survivors from alien invasion of Earth
- it's a series
- a review [here](https://www.abebooks.co.uk/9781899884001/Minds-Empire-Warren-James-Palmer-1899884009/plp) explicitly mentions "King Arthur legends".
- [the summary of the second book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07C64W5RQ), *Dominator* (1996), has the aliens coming back with bigger, badder ships, and Earth relying on *Excalibur*, a spaceship which was found under Stonehenge, to protect it. *Excalibur* is then presumably quite high-tech.
- Moss, the protagonist, has "mental powers". He might, or might not, be able to "mentally connect to the ship".

Not sure if checks:

- I can't find anything about Morgan, but there is little to be found online on that series, so maybe it was a later twist that nobody wanted to spoil?
- Merlin is featured, but then again, Merlin is never far from Excalibur, so that's not much of an indication.

---

Found with the Google query `book excalibur spaceship` which returned [this self-answered Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/5xpwn7/scifi_series_from_20ish_years_ago_young_adult/):

> **Scifi series from 20ish years ago, young adult, kids book, alien occupation, London, Merlin, Stonehenge, spaceship excalibur, telepathy/telekenesis**
>
> Series of pulpy young adult scifi books follows a british boy, initially living in London on an alien occupied earth. Boy character leaves London after botched assasination attempt on an alien possibly at a theater, finds spaceship excalibur and merlin under stonehenge?, unlocks latent telepathy/telekenesis and over 2 or 3 more books takes the fight to the alien planet. Bought in 1995 +/-10 as paperbacks from a budget bookshop on Charing Cross Road. Possibly published or printed by independant 'ripping yarns'.

Comment: Thank you the Dyason certainly rings a bell. I do believe this is it. The Morgana elements came from a vague remembrance of a woman from the legends being on the aliens home plant and Merlin knows her and has been battling her manipulations for centuries. I just assume it was Morgana or at least an aspect of her. Now I know what the series is called I can reread and check.

Comment: @kimchurch you're welcome, enjoy the re-read​! :) And don't hesitate to come back and tell us if your memory of Morgana was faithful!

Comment: I'm going to get that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Almost surely **not** the answer (no Morgana, which features prominently in your question, no "backward" alien ships), but otherwise a close fit should anyone come here with this in mind:

- starship called Excalibur, manned by Earthmen (well, sort of)
- Earth invaded / menaced by galactic aliens
- an invasion (actually extermination) fleet

...all appear in David Weber's [*The Excalibur Alternative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Excalibur_Alternative), chronologically in year 2097 if memory serves, more or less last installment of the "Earth Legions" (formerly *Ranks of Bronze*) series.

The funny thing is that this *other* piece of question

> Strangely the aliens have ships which are nuclear based and not much more advanced technology wise than second world war

appears in *The Road not Taken*, which has a plot point in common (aliens "invading" and more or less unwittingly supplying space flight to Earthmen) with Anderson's *The High Crusade*, itself similar to *Earth Legions*.

Comment: You mention 3 different books and I'm not sure if you intend for any, all, or none of them to answer the question.

Comment: @eshier well, none. Yet, it often happens to me that I look for some work and land on some question which closely matches mine, and yet refers to a different book I wasn't even aware of. So I thought to add an answer that - while probably not helping the OP - might be of use to some other passer-by. I've been helped time and again by such 'non-answers'.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the Falcon Banner series, by Chris Lydon I believe.  Theres a few books in the series I believe, 4 or 5 last time I checked. But I think that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you provide some details on why this matches? There's already an accepted answer. And while we welcome incorrect but matching answers (because they may help future querents who are searching for that book), we need more details. :)